# How to find inactive questions

Tags: feature-request, questions

There is a tab called **Active** in the question tab. Is there any way to find the inactive questions in the StackOverflow?

Comment: "Unanswered" questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you'd expect to find there. The active tab already lists *every single question* ever asked - they're just sorted by which one has had something happen to them most recently. If you want to see old questions which haven't been touched in a long time, you can just skip to the last page and work backwards.

Answer (score 7):

This is the custom Search in StackOverFlow Search Box.

**[swift] lastactive:..6m is:q**

Here **[swift]** is the tag Name. **lastactive:..6m** This is short list the last 6 months questions. **is:q** This will return only questions.

Like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D%20lastactive%3A..6m%20is%3Aq) example.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer